# Asynchronous callbacks in a meteor app

Tags: node.js, twitter, meteor

I'm using the ntwitter node.js module to access twitter's streaming API from inside a meteor app, but when trying to insert into a collection inside the callback function the app crashes:

```
twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {'track':'whatever'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
      //logging the data coming back works fine
      console.log(data);
      //the next line throws "Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber"
      Tweets.insert(data); 
  });
});
```

Is there a recommended approach to using async callbacks in the context of Meteors linear execution model? I tried wrapping the insertion inside a new Fiber which seems to work but I'm unsure of any implications it may have.

I found this http://gist.io/3443021 which was helpful but I'm still not sure which approach would suit my particular case so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We used a different design pattern. In the async callback, we act more like a device driver and simply buffer the result in memory:

```
var tweets = [];

twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {'track':'whatever'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
      //logging the data coming back works fine
      console.log(data);
      //the next line throws "Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber"
      tweets.push(data); 
  }); 
});
```

and then later on, back within the normal Meteor execution environment within a Fiber, either in a timer or a result of a function, we drain the tweets array and do the insert then. A Javascript array doesn't care whether it is running within a Fiber or not.

In our case, we are doing this with asynch IMAP email rather than tweets, but the analogy still holds.

Comment: while this would work, in my case it would somewhat negate the point of having realtime stream data as I'm using the streaming api to not having to poll in the first place

Comment: Where's the polling? This is the same callback you had previously. The polling is not on the twitter stream, it is on the in-memory buffer, which is nothing more than a quick lookup, not a poll of twitter.

Comment: Well wouldn't I have to poll the array at some sort of interval? I'd rather update the collection in realtime if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your callback in `Meteor.bindEnvironment` like so:

```
twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {'track':'whatever'}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
      //logging the data coming back works fine
      console.log(data);
      //the next line throws "Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber"
      Tweets.insert(data); 
  }));
});
```

According to [this SO post about Async wrappers on the Meteor Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097503/what-is-the-difference-between-all-of-the-async-wrappers-in-meteor), you want to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` when you are managing a callback using a third party api/npm module (which looks to be the case)

`Meteor.bindEnvironment` creates a new Fiber and copies the current Fiber's variables and environment to the new Fiber.